# Do any languages let you remove a variable from scope?

Tags: scala, programming-languages

There's an occasional source of bugs in my Scala code, when I do a number of operations in order to a variable, creating lots of intermediate variables.

```
class SomeClass(name: String) {

  def doSomeThings() {
    val canonicalizedName = canonicalizeName(name)
    val boozbangledName = boozbangle(canonicalizedName)
    val plobberedName = plobber(boozbangledName)
    val flemmedName = flem(boozbangledName) // bug!  should have been flem(plobberedName)
    // (more code)
    doAThing(flemmedName) // correct!
    doAnotherThing(name)     // bug!  should have been doAnotherThing(flemmedName)
  }
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this sort of bug, in any programming language - e.g. remove "deprecated" variables from scope?  I could use a `var` to prevent the first bug, but it still doesn't prevent the second:

```
class SomeClass(name: String) {

  def doSomeThings() {
    var fixedName = name
    fixedName = canonicalizeName(fixedName)
    fixedName = boozbangle(fixedName)
    fixedName = plobber(fixedName)
    fixedName = flem(fixedName)
    // (more code)
    doAThing(fixedName) // good!
    doAnotherThing(name)     // bug!  should have been doAnotherThing(flemmedName)
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Some would argue that the first way is actually more readable. It clearly indicates that the order matters when calling the methods.

Comment: How about simply putting these first four lines in a separate method which does all the intermediate operations and returns flemmedName? Then you will have only one variable in doSomeThings(). Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

While getting confused with the variable names may indicate bad naming, duplication or violation of the law of demeter, it is actually possible to implement a "val-deprecation" feature in Scala using macros.

As I have just started learning how to write macros I cannot provide you a satisfying implementation, but - to illustrate what I have in mind - I tried to come up with the most trivial implementation: Checking whether the name of the val is contained in the expressions. Also, the macro only returns a `Unit` expression, which could be generalized using generic type parameters. However, it should be possible to come up with a better looking, more powerful implementation.

Note that macros need to be compiled before your other code, so you need to implement them in a separate project.

The naive macro implementation could look as follows:

```
package mymacros

object Macros {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros

  def deprecatedValue_impl(c: scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context)(value: c.Expr[Any])(action: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val valueName = show(value.tree)
    if(show(action).contains(valueName)) {
      throw DeprecatedValueUsed(valueName)
    }
    action
  }

  def deprecatedValue(value: Any)(action: => Unit): Unit = macro deprecatedValue_impl

}

case class DeprecatedValueUsed(valueName: String) extends Error // Add a nice error message here
```

Which would produce errors at compile time, if `action` contains the identifier of the provided `val`.

```
object DeprecateNames {
  import mymacros.Macros._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val flobberwobber = "hello"
    val flabberwabber = "world"
    deprecatedValue(flobberwobber){
      // println(flobberwobber) doesn't compile
      println(flabberwabber)
      // println(flobberwobber + flabberwabber)  doesn't compile
      println("hello" + "world")
      // println("flobberwobber") doesn't compile
    }
  }
}
```

Note that, according to [SI-5778](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5778), using `Tree` instead of `Expr` and thereby allowing call-by-name parameters is only possible since Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you really want to do is compose all of those functions. That captures the idea of a chain of operations, with none of the intermediate values "leaking out". Assuming they were all `Function1` instances (you could use the `_` operator to coerce methods to be treated as functions), they have an `andThen` operator that lets you compose them. So you could do something like:

```
class SomeClass(name: String) {
  def doSomeThings() {
    val processChain = Seq(canonicalizeName, boozbangle, plobber, flem, doAThing, doAnotherThing)
    processChain.reduce(_ andThen _)(name)
  }
}
```

In other words, these unary functions are a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup), with composition (`andThen`) as the *operator*. Well, really, they're furthermore a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Monoids_in_computer_science) with the `identity` function as the *identity*, but we're not using that property here, since it's a predetermined list of functions; that would come into play if you wanted to `fold` a variable list, and use `identity` as the base case.

The other thing that occurred to me is that you can use the type system to accomplish the safety you want as well. If you want to tag intermediate values as being "unsuitable" for any function but the one their destined for, you might want to define single argument `case class`es to act kind of like enforced [sigils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29), and then if you give your functions the appropriate input and output types, you can keep your intermediate variables, but they just won't be usable in any other way than the types will allow.

And to answer your question of whether any language allows removal of variables, I know that Python has the [`del` keyword](http://programming.mesexemples.com/python/language-basics-python/python-deleting-variables/) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good suggestions already.  Here's another technique that you might find helpful for this problem:

```
class SomeClass(name: String) {
  def doSomeThings() {
    val flemmedName = {
      val plobberedName = {
        val canonicalizedName = canonicalizeName(name)
        val boozbangledName = boozbangle(canonicalizedName)
        plobber(boozbangledName)
      }
      flem(boozbangledName) // compilation error
    }
    // (more code)
    doAThing(flemmedName) // correct!
    doAnotherThing(name)     // sorry, can't help with this one
  }
}
```